# (WP7) Windows live SDK user logout or sign in as a different user

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, sdk, live, logout

I've been looking for a solution on how to make the user logout and still be able to login using different email account. Currently, it automatically signs in the first account that you've entered.

My source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shelly_guos_ms_blog/archive/2011/09/20/get-started-on-live-sdk-for-windows-phone.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use "wl.signin" in your scopes. If you have been testing your app with this in, go into your account preferences for your live account and remove this option from the app's access. 
This will now allow more than one user to sign in.

```
private LiveAuthClient authClient;

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.authClient = new LiveAuthClient("yourclientidhere");
}
```

then you can call `this.authClient.Logout()`; when you want to change users.